# Что означает знак Эрудит?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, локализация, знаки

Описание знака Эрудит гласит

> Дать ответы на авторские вопросы с общим рейтингом 15 баллов, по 20 из
>   первых 40 меток.

Я не понимаю, что это означает. Точнее я понимаю, что сумма баллов за ответы должна быть не менее 15 в метке, но далее темный лес. Цифры 20 и 40 что означают? Это популярные метки, это метки отвечающего? Может стоит описать этот знак более подробно? В текущем варианте довольно сложно понять, за что его присваивают даже имея опыт работы с сайтом.

Comment: Сделал вопрос-"предложение", чтобы [изменить перевод для этой метки](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3216/).

Comment: @GlebKemarsky спасибо!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Есть множество всех [меток, использованных на сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags). На странице по ссылке эти метки как раз отсортированы по популярности, то есть по количеству вопросов, отмеченных каждой меткой.

Берём 40 первых меток, т.е. самые популярные. Если по 20 из них у вас есть хотя бы 15 баллов рейтинга (не репутации), то знак ваш.

Кстати, не на каждом сайте можно получить знак Эрудит. Необходимо, чтобы на сайте было не менее 40 меток, каждая из которых имеет не менее 200 использований. Например, на Ru.SO сейчас 136 таких меток (знак доступен), а на Мете Ru.SO – всего 5.

Alexander Barakin подсказал также [запрос по SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/505201/generalist-progression-see-all-top-40-tags), показывающий вашу статистику по 40 наиболее популярным меткам.

Чтобы не заморачиваться с подсчётами, можно использовать приложение [Stinking Badges](http://agent86ix.github.io/stackapps/badge) (там этот знак называется Generalist). Ниже подсказка, где в списке сайтов находится наш.

[image]

Comment: Не пойму, как в этом приложении ruSO найти...

Comment: @Qwertiy промотайте до конца списка сайтов, потом немного наверх.

Comment: @Qwertiy скриншот сделал, взгляните.

Comment: @Qwertiy, есть [запрос в data.so](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/469260). недостаток: метки на русском отображаются некорректно. но можно догадаться, глядя на страницу с метками в своём профиле, отсортированную по количеству голосов.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо за ссылку, добавил в ответ.

Comment: Возможно я ошибаюсь, но необходимо набрать 15 голосов за ответ, а не 15 баллов репутации.

Comment: Хотя из списка награжденных участников следует обратное.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ни то, ни другое. Нужно 15 баллов рейтинга по метке. Уточнил формулировку.

Comment: Вот это поворот! Спасибо! Надо бы уточнить описание самой метки в соседнем вопросе.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вроде бы там уже всё верно. Нет?

Comment: Наверное, все в порядке. Прочитал не так.