# Описание знака “Эрудит”

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

1. Нынешнее описание [трудно понять](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3214/):

> Дать ответы на авторские вопросы с общим рейтингом 15 баллов, по 20 из первых 40 меток.

2. Заметил что [на английском сайте](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist) говорится не об "авторских вопросах", а о "не-общих ответах":

> **Generalist**. Provide non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags

Давайте придумаем новый перевод?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю:

> Набрать по 15 баллов рейтинга за ответы по 20 меткам из 40 наиболее популярных. Общие ответы не в счёт.

Ещё бы хорошо сделать "40 наиболее популярных" ссылкой на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular

UPD. А если общие ответы можно не упоминать, то второе предложение не нужно:

> Набрать по 15 баллов рейтинга за ответы по 20 меткам из 40 наиболее популярных.

Comment: За общие ответы и так рейтинг не набирается.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Тогда второе предложение лучше убрать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Это может быть далеко не очевидно для читающего описания знака. Если в оригинале есть "non-wiki", думаю, имеет смысл оставить.

Comment: "Не в счёт" — это разговорный оборот, по-моему. "Не учитываются" тогда уж, если в одно предложение никак не уложиться. Правда я бы просто заменил "авторские" на "необщие".

Comment: @Discord Думал про вариант в "[канцелярском стиле](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3222/208926)" . Мне он меньше по душе, чем разговорный вариант, но могу быть предвзятым.

Comment: Если не возражаете, я бы оставил «авторские вопросы». То есть `Набрать по 15 баллов рейтинга за ответы на авторские вопросы по 20 меткам из 40 наиболее популярных.`

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Почему вы хотите их оставить? Чем они важны?

Comment: Как мне кажется, это не очевидно. Я бы сказал, тут вся формулировка не очевидна. Плюс, в английском варианте есть. Думаете упоминания про «авторство» совсем не нужно?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Описание перегружено сущностями: отвечайте на вопросы, получайте за ответы голоса, копите рейтинг по метке, по 20 разным меткам, по 20 любым меткам из топ 40... И кстати, если вы знаете, что такое общие ответы, и успели принять в них участие, то в получении знака это не поможет :) Чтобы понять смысл с первого прочтения, хочется убрать всё, без чего можно обойтись. Слово "авторские", кажется, нигде больше не используется. [Tour] рассказывает про "ответы", к ним все привыкли. И есть "общие ответы" как фича. Зачем вводить новый термин?

Comment: Согласен. Поправил.

Answer (score 2):

Вариация на тему (без выкидывания информации и разговорных оборотов):

> Набрать по 15 баллов рейтинга за необщие ответы по 20 меткам из 40 самых популярных.

Comment: Придётся сразу писать объяснение, что такое необщие ответы.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Почему? Понятие "общие ответы" объясняется в справке. Необщие ответы — это посты, которые "ответы", но которые не "общие".

Comment: Потому что у слова "общий" есть и другой смысл, отличный от того, что в справке. "Общий вопрос" и "общий ответ" - это вопрос на общую тему или некое обобщающее рассуждение. Чтобы видеть в них  именно коллективную работу авторов, надо сначала прочитать справку.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Чтобы знать, что такое "рейтинг", как он считается, и от чего зависит, тоже нужно читать справку (если не мету), но вы же не будете это всё расписывать. Главное, чтобы все слова можно было найти.

Comment: 1) Рейтинг - базовое понятие. Общеупотребительное и понятное. С общими ответами сложнее, их приходится растолковывать через вики. А "авторских" или "необщих" ответов в справке и нет, наверное. 2) Описание должно снимать вопросы, а не добавлять их.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky "Общие вопросы" — на нашем сайте точно такое же "общеупотребительное", как "вики" в оригинале. В чём именно разница? Функционирование частицы "не" знающим русский язык объяснять не требуется.

Comment: Думаю, общие вопросы становятся привычными для тех, кто основательно поселяется на сайте. А описание знака нацелено и на случайного посетителя тоже. Поэтому я за то, чтобы заинтересовать этого читателя нашим сайтом, а не заставлять его искать справку, чтобы понять, что же он только что прочитал.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Я не наблюдаю решения описанной вами проблемы в ваших предложениях. В одной версии слово выкинуто (вы пожертвовали содержательностью), в другой версии слово "общий" обёрнуто громоздкой конструкцией (то есть лучше ни в каком приближении не стало). Слово для понимания сути знака необязательно, но важно при разборе деталей функционала.

Comment: Ваше мнение услышал.

Answer (score 2):

Другое пояснение про общие ответы:

> Набрать по 15 баллов рейтинга за ответы по 20 меткам из 40 наиболее
>   популярных. Участие в общих ответах не учитывается.

Comment: По-вашему, если "необщий" заменить на конструкцию "ответы, которые не являются общими", то всё становится понятнее?

Comment: @Discord 1) По-моему, здесь другая конструкция. 2) Будет здорово найти короткое и понятное описание.

Comment: Конструкция другая, суть та же: бесполезная конструкция, которая ничего не объясняет. Причём ваша версия ещё хуже, потому что "участие" можно интерпретировать многими способами. :) Пока что все объяснения зависят от слова "общий" (кроме объяснений, из которых слово выкинуто), и объяснению этого слова в описании делать нечего. Не объясняется же, что такое "вики", в оригинальном описании, хотя нюансов у "вики" немало.

Comment: @Discord Ваше мнение услышал.